# Is ampersand(&) important in this case?

Tags: c++

What's the difference between

```
Complex operator+(Complex& A, Complex& B) {
    double re=A.getReal()+B.getReal();
    double im=A.getImg()+B.getImg();
    Complex C(re, im);
    return C;
}
```

and this(without &):

```
Complex operator+(Complex A, Complex B) {
    double re=A.getReal()+B.getReal();
    double im=A.getImg()+B.getImg();
    Complex C(re, im);
    return C;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what the meaning of the `&` is?

Comment: If anything, it should be `const Complex&`. `Complex&` doesn't let you do e.g. `Complex(1,2) + Complex(3,4)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case the overload of the + operator receives as parameters a reference of A and a reference of B. This means that no copy constructor is called. Also, if you modify A (for example) by setting the real part to 0, you will see this modification at A’s real part after returning from the function.

In the second case, the overload of + operator received a copy of A and a copy of B. In this case the copy constructor is called. Any modification to A or B inside the function are not visible after the function ends.

Why is sometimes better to avoid the call of the copy constructor? It depends on the members of your class. Imagine that your class has a member that stores a vector with 1.000.000 elements. The copy constructor should allocate a one million elements vector and then copy its data. This operation takes time. So in this case is better to avoid the call of the copy constructor. But if the members of your class are simple double values, as in your example, you can use your second definition without problems.

Also, in the first case, if you don’t want to allow any modifications to A or B, you can use a const reference, like bellow:

`Complex operator+(const Complex& A, const Complex& B);`

Answer (score 3):

Primarily, it is important to not use a reference to non-const for a function that doesn't modify the object through the reference. Using a reference to non-const will prevent the operator from being used with rvalue arguments.

Using a reference in this case may be important or it might not be. It is only relevant for optimisation purpose. If the function is not used in a hot part of the program, then its speed  may not be important.

Assuming its speed is important, then the importance of the argument type depends on on many factors. For example if function is expanded inline then the choice probably doesn't matter at all. If it isn't inlined, then it can depend on the capabilities of the target system. On one system, the reference may be faster, on another system the value may be faster, while on others there may not be significant difference.

You can find out both which is faster, and whether it is significant to your program by measuring the different choices.

Note that if you do use a reference, then you should use a reference to const here.

Comment: A reference for a small data type, like `int&` (when used non-mutating-ly, so should have been `const`) or `int const&` is likely to be a pessimization.  Although compiler optimizers are devilishly clever.